# Does 'LOCK AND ERASE' in Android Device Manager delete all the data in a lost phone?

Tags: android-device-manager, lost-phone

My Friend's mobile was lost yesterday and I tried to delete all his data using the android device manager. But it shows only the "ring button" and "Enable Lock and Erase". I Clicked "Enable Lock and Erase". I want to confirm weather it has performed already automatically when mobile data is switched on, or does the user need to confirm to perform the next step. Please Help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ADM will notify the account owner when the wipe is successful, and the location it occurred, by email.

Once the event is set in ADM, it will occur automatically as soon as the device makes contact with Google servers. It doesn't matter if it's immediately or after several months or even years (theoretically).

Answer (score -1):

In my Nexus 5 after sending "enable lock and erase" command "Android Device Manager" feature automatically enabled. If device gets online yo can wipe device from Android Device Manager webpage. You should check https://www.google.com/android/devicemanager often to do this operation.